# C++ Base64 Encode/Decode arbitary binary data

Tags: c++, binary, base64, decode, encode

I need 2 fucntions, encode_base64, decond_base64

The following should be the signature....

```
std::string encode_base64(const void* buf, int size);
void* decode_base64(const std::string& b64string);
```

Basically, i need 2 functions able to encode/decode ANY arbiturary binary data, such as a class,
structure, class or structures with pointers that points to data, etc. etc....
and once encoded, it is a string representation of that binary data, and i can store it, save it, transfer it, over the internet, whatever, and decode back to my original structure having the same exact data.

I cant find a working example on the internet, most examples use some form of string as intput and output. I am not just working with strings, but actual binary data.

So for usage, let say i have class Foo, which has a bunch of fields and data, i encode it. it gives me a base64 string. and decode it. it gives me a void* which i can cast back into Foo and gives me the exact data.

Remember, class Foo or any data object i put in can contain pointers, data, byte arrays, pointer to data, pointer to pointer, whatever, i just need the exact data that when pass in, comes back out my data.

Comment: You can't just dump your memory convert it to a stream receive it at the other end and interpret it as a valid object (or collection of object). What you are looking for is called serialization: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization. Don't try to write that yourself though, you're probably better of using some exisiting technology like gRPC to do these kind of things. See : https://grpc.io/ (If I remember correctly I think the underlying protobuf does the base64 encoding for you)

Comment: ok thanks, i guess i'll have to redesign my stuff

Comment: Probably, there's too many pitfalls on the copy memory route. It just takes one compiler setting mismatch to break everything. You might also look at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html though I've never used that myself. (boost is now at version 1.78, but this doc I could quickly find)